# Plotting data contained in .mat file with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, octave

I have a file myfile.mat exported from octave, it contains three matrices X, Y, U all of them have same size and I want to plot surface U where X, Y are the x and y components of surface U. I can do it in octave with the following code:

```
surf(X,Y,U)
```

But I want to do it in python also. I am using pythonxy and for plotting the data in python first of all I import the data with spyder GUI interactively after I saw the matrices in variable explorer in spyder I implement the following codes

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, U, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
```

But I see just a blank figure window.
Here is the data [myfile.mat](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/483032/myfile-zip.html)

Comment: can you post the myfile.mat?

Comment: I edit the post by adding the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are forgetting to include a call to `plt.show()` at the end. This function has no analog in MATLAB/Octave, but is absolutely required in matplotlib. Also, please be aware that `plt.show()` doesn't seem to work properly inside of loops in some Python environments, so if you are trying to generate multiple images at once (for example, generating 10 different figures inside of a "for" loop) that may be a hidden source of problems for you as well. Furthermore, you need to define a colormap using the `cmap=cm.<whatever>` option in the call to the `ax.plot_surface()` method. A list of all the colormaps that you may use can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). And finally, your strides are too large for the tiny little data file that you included. I've appended example code and the resulting image below. I left out setting `alpha=0.3` because it is unnecessary for this data (there is nothing in front of or behind anything else) but you may put it back in if you like; the code will still work.

[image: Example surface plot]

```
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = scipy.io.loadmat('myfile.mat')
X = data['X']
Y = data['Y']
U = data['U']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, U, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(surf)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I had  forgotten plt.show() code in the post but actually i was implementing it. Nevertheless the codes didn't work and i gave a small data for simplicity actually my data is bigger. Anyway I adopted your codes according to my data and they work fine. Thank you for your answer.